# c++ - Implementation of internal aggregation in the following case

Tags: c++, pointers, aggregation

This project i am working on uses pointers, inheritance and internal aggregation (rule of 3). I understand the concept of rule of 3 and have read a few posts here about it. The basic thing that needs to be implemented is to have a room class where each room has several meetings (Internal Aggregation). Room has the following attributes:

string d_name

int d_nMeetings

Meeting** d_schedule.

I know that the rule of three needs to be implemented in Meeting** d_schedule and d_schedule would be an array of meeting pointers which calls an array of pointers which points to meetings. 
ButI'm not too sure however on how it would work in this case (in d_schedule or in the function below (in meeting.h) which reads void add(Meeting*). The following is my code:

Meeting.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "item.h"

class Meeting: public Item{
protected:
  bool d_coffee;
  std::vector<std::string> d_participants;

public:
  Meeting(std::string, Time, int, bool, std::vector<std::string>, int);
  void print();
};
```

Meeting.cpp:

```
#include "meeting.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "item.h"

Meeting::Meeting(std::string _what, Time _deadline, int _duration, bool _coffee, std::vector<std::string> _participants, int _priority = 0) :      Item(_what, _deadline, _duration, priority = 0)
{
  d_coffee = _coffee;
  d_participants = _participants;
}

void Meeting::print()
{
   Item::print();
}
```

Room.h:

```
#include "meeting.h"

class Room{
private:
  std::string d_name;
  Meeting** d_schedule;
  int d_nMeetings;

public:
  Room(std::string _name);
  void setName(std::string);
  std::string getName();
  bool add(Meeting*);
  void print();
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `std::vector<Meeting*> d_schedule;` instead of reimplementing the same functionality.

If you still want to use `Meeting** d_schedule;`, checkout how `vector` data structure works:
http://codefreakr.com/how-is-c-stl-implemented-internally/

Basically you'll have to allocate some fixed array and reallocate and copy over it every time it fills up.